# php code to run elasticsearch query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

Im newbie to elasticsearch. I wanted to search mysql dB using elasticsearch. I want and get the result. I even installed elastica for this. But Im not getting any results from this code:

```
<?php
 require_once '/home/babloo/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Elastica_Client();
$index = $client->getIndex('jdbc');
$index->getType('jdbc');

$query_string = new Elastica_Query_QueryString('ashish');
$query_string->setFields(array('name'));    
$query = new Elastica_Query($query_string);

$index->refresh();
$searchResults = $index->search($query);
?>
```

where Am i going wrong?

Comment: i don't see your connecting to a database, is that done some where out of the stage?

Comment: @DevZer0: No... How to do with that?

Comment: I don't know my self, i checked the documentation its very rusty. I am downloading elastica now if i get a chance to check it out i will get back to you.

Comment: you cannot use elasticsearch to search a mySQL db. Think of it like another database, but optomised for searching. You need to get your data into elasticsearch from mySQL first, then send queries to the elasticsearch server. Search around for ways of importing data, I recommend playing with command line cURL statements to start.

Answer (score 0):

Improve the syntax and follow the steps:
1) Do set error reporting ON

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
   session_start();
```

2) require 'vendor/autoload.php';    (Installed using composer)

3) Create Objects

```
   $client = new Elasticsearch\Client();
   $elasticaClient = new Elastica\Client();
   $reque=new Elastica\Request($elasticaClient);
```

4) Program Example

```
$index = $elasticaClient->getIndex('test');
$index->create(array(), true);
$type = $index->getType('test');
$type->addDocument(new Elastica\Document(1, array('username' => 'ruflin')));
$index->refresh();

$query = array(
    'query' => array(
        'query_string' => array(
            'query' => 'ruflin',
        )
    )
);
 //$typee =$reque->GET;
$path = $index->getName() . '/' . $type->getName() . '/_search';

$response = $elasticaClient->request($path, $reque::GET, $query);
$responseArray = $response->getData();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($responseArray);
```

REFERENCE LINKS

## COMPOSER

b) https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
H) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-your-vps-running-ubuntu